# crosscompile linux module w/o target kernel headers but target Module.symvers available

Tags: module, linux-kernel, cross-compiling

I'm toying with an embedded system (Bebop Drone) running linux. I have:

1. linux kernel **source tree** (3.4.11) from manufacturer (thx to GPL)
2. **.config** file from manufacturer
3. **NO "kernel-headers"** from manufacturer
4. **NO /lib/modules/X/build** area on the device
5. living target kernel and some modules on the device (arm7)
6. Ubuntu 15 as cross compile platform
7. Modules.symvers recreated from running kernel thanks to
   https://glandium.org/blog/?p=2664&cpage=1#comment-854639

I want to add module  option.ko  to the device. 
I configured the needed options in .configm usbserial, usb_wwan, et.al. 
(via make oldconfig, make menuconf)

All attempts to load a module onto the target system fail with dmegs stating the ko file's module_layout having a different CRC from what the kernel wants.
Hexediting the "correct" CRC into the ko file only shifts the complaint to another symbol needed by the module.

**Whatever I try while cross-compiling, the *.ko files have non-matching symbols CRCs!**

I've no idea WHEN to sneak in the "non-matching" Module.symvers from the target system, the last stage of modul crosscompilation busts my trickery and recreates Module.symvers, overwriting the desired target CRCs.

**Why does that symvers issue arise in the first place,** considering that I'm using the very source tree the manufacturer is publishing (and living kernel supposedly is using)?

How can one fix that symvers mismatch issue and **generate "new" modules for that old running kernel**?

TIA

Comment: Just build kernel from sources (on host), using **entire** `.config` file you have "from manufacturer". Such a way you will have all kernel symbols same as on the target's kernel.

Comment: doesn't work. Extract source, cp .config file, make zImage, make modules produces a Module.symvers which does NOT match the CRCs of the living kernel.  How ciritical is compiler type?   Where is die doc with what compler version/flags etc parrot has compiled it?

Comment: `How ciritical is compiler type?` Compiler **type** could be critical. Compiler **version** difference may be less critical for CRC. You may try to replace incompatible `Module.symvers` of the kernel you have compiled with target's `Module.symvers` file, and then compile you module.

Comment: Compile type was that culprit: Using exactly what was specified in /proc/version, Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2012 03-57 did regenerate the CRCs of the running system !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we maintain question posts **without** "SOLVED" marks in the title or body. Instead, we allow the OP to [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) his question and, after some amount of time passed, [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it. This is effectively means that OP has found decision for his problem. Remove(rollback) `[SOLVED]` suffix from your question's title, make your last comment as an answer, and mark it as accepted.

Comment: And of course, with the CRCs build correctly one doesn't have to try and recrated Module.symvers anymore.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

case solved, the compiler IS critical, it must be the one specifiec in /proc/version, see fourth comment above.